# Upgrading to macOS Catalina with Android Studio

Tags: catalina, mojave, xcode

I have a MacBook Pro mid-2014, running macOS Mojave 10.14.6.

I have built an iOS app using Xcode 10.1, but when I wanted to upload it to the App Store, I came upon the following message:

> ERROR ITMS-90725: "SDK Version Issue. This app was built with the iOS 12.1 SDK. As of June 30, 2020, all apps for iPhone or iPad must be built with the iOS 13 SDK or later, included with Xcode 11 or later."

I entered to the App Store, but I couldn't update to Xcode's latest version, as I don't have macOS Catalina installed. The problem is that I need Android Studio on my computer, but according to Android Studio's website, it is supported up to macOS Mojave, not Catalina.

My question is, is it safe to upgrade to macOS Catalina and keep using Android Studio? Or is there another way to solve this? Maybe installing a different version of Xcode that will run on macOS Mojave and supports iOS 13?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have installed Xcode 11.3 from Apple Developers website.

This version supports iOS 13 SDK and macOS 10.14.4, which is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have sufficient space on your disk, you could try partitioning it into two separate volumes from Disk Utility, then installing macOS Catalina onto the second partition.  While requiring more disk space, this has the highest performance and the easiest means to copy files between the two different OSes and developer environments.

You could also create a macOS Catalina virtual machine in most of the popular emulators, such as VMWare Fusion, Virtualbox or Parallels.  (Apple's EULA for the macOS specifically allows running it under emulation on Apple hardware.)  By sacrificing some performance, you gain much more portability, and could store and run the VM from any external storage.

Answer (score 0):

The ask is the versions to upgrade to get to Catalina macOS 10.15.4/7. Therefore...

- Xcode 12.4
- iOS 14.4, iPadOS 14.4
- flutter SDK v 2.10.3 / Dart v 2.16.1

Please note, Flutter 3 doesn't support Catalina; so you'll need to upgrade to Big Sur, I believe, to use the latest version of Flutter (v3).